# Using thunk to handle onClick events. Is it more efficient?

Tags: reactjs

```
function MyComponent() {
  const handleSomething = (arg) => () => {
    console.log(arg);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span onClick={handleSomething("Hello")}>Do something</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I just came in contact with the above thunk sintax and was told it performs better than the code below.

```js
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span onClick={()=>{ console.log("Hello") }}>Do something</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Won't **handleSomething** run on every render, thus adding an extra step ?

Or maybe the compiler has some clever optimization that makes thunk faster than inline ?

Comment: Re-rendering only happens on DOM changes. Defining functions in the component is much cleaner than writing them inside the JSX template.

Comment: I understand is cleaner and quite like it, but I don't get how it could perform faster.

Comment: React components contain code, and JSX contains HTML with data bindings. That is how React was designed. Why would writing a function in the component be slower?

Comment: Because the thunk function will run when the component renders and return another function for the onClick, while writing the function directly inside the onClick skips running the handleSomething.

Answer (score 0):

In class components, just use [memoize](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#memoize):

```
import memoize from "lodash-es/memoize";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span onClick={handleSomething("Hello")}>Do something</span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleSomething = memoize(arg => () => {
    console.log(arg);
  }); 
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with lodash, but function components have useMemo and useCallback hooks for memoization, however I haven't quite wrapped my head around the concept and what it does exactly.
Anyway, this question is more about one-line inexpensive functions that could be written directly inline within the onClick handler without compromising readability.
Maybe the compiler has some clever optimization that makes thunk faster than inline ?